# Has anyone tried to use IPython with the Hylang syntax?

Tags: python, ipython

You can use Hylang with this magic:

```
In [1]: %%script hy
(print "Hello, Cuddlefish!")                                                                                             
   ...: 
=> Hello, Cuddlefish!
=> hy 0.9.12


In [2]:
```

I want to use it directly:

```
In [1]: (print "Hello, Cuddlefish!")
Hello, Cuddlefish!

Int [2]:
```

Comment: So you basically want an IPython-like REPL, only for Hy instead of Python?

Comment: IPython is insanely useful. The ideal would be some customization of IPython which will enable us to use IPython with the Hylang syntax.

Comment: You can get support in the modern frontends (`ipython notebook`, `ipython qtconsole`, `ipython console`) by implementing a Hy kernel - a process that responds to messages asking it to execute code, find tab completions, etc. [This README](https://github.com/dsblank/simple_kernel#simple_kernel) is a pretty good list of resources for doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try out my [hymagic](http://github.com/yardsale8/hymagic) module. You can install it using

```
$ pip install hymagic
```

Load the magic using

```
%load_ext hymagic
```

Use `%hylang` for one line and `%%hylang` for a whole cell. For example

```
%hylang (+ 1 2 3)
```

and

```
%%hylang
(defn hello []
   (print "hello world"))
(hello)
```

Answer (score 2):

One can instead install the [hy kernel](https://github.com/bollwyvl/hy_kernel/), where there's no need to prefix

> %hylang

at the start of every cell.

Answer (score 0):

(*Late to the party answer*)

The Hy kernel mentioned in other comments (`hy_kernel`) isn't maintained anymore.

The actively developed one is now [Calysto Hy](https://github.com/Calysto/calysto_hy), based on the [Metakernel](https://github.com/Calysto/metakernel).